# How to style border for one side in ttk widgets? Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

My question is simple. I want to know how to style one border side of a themed Tkinter widget specifically a button or a TButton?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Sujay my expected output is a button or a frame with border color of one side

Comment: So you want only one side pf your frame with different colour

Comment: @Sujay yes I want one side of the border to be color for my button yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this? It is a modified version

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MyLabel(Frame):
    '''inherit from Frame to make a label with customized border'''
    def __init__(self, parent, myborderwidth=0, mybordercolor=None,
                 myborderplace='center', *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=mybordercolor)
        self.propagate(False) # prevent frame from auto-fitting to contents
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, *args, **kwargs) # make the label

        # pack label inside frame according to which side the border
        # should be on. If it's not 'left' or 'right', center the label
        # and multiply the border width by 2 to compensate
        if myborderplace == 'left':
            self.button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        elif myborderplace == 'right':
            self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        else:
            self.button.pack()
            myborderwidth = myborderwidth * 2

        # set width and height of frame according to the req width
        # and height of the label
        self.config(width=self.button.winfo_reqwidth() + myborderwidth)
        self.config(height=self.button.winfo_reqheight())


root=Tk()
MyLabel(root, text='Hello World', myborderwidth=4, mybordercolor='red',
        myborderplace='left').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is something I am looking for but I want to do this for button and for TTK not normal tkinter